# Why is only one row exported to excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I try to export my pandas data frame to excel only one row exports.

The data base is created during a large loop which basically gives the output:

```
                                    Names  Average Selling Price
0  ★ Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)               2.418605
                                    Names  Average Selling Price
0  ★ Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)                1.69697
                                    Names  Average Selling Price
0  ★ Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)                    1.0
```

but on a larger scale.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from numpy import mean
import re
import numpy
import statistics
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd




workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('JohnsWaxpeerDatabase.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook.close()


item=[]
listo=[]
URL = (
        "https://waxpeer.com/api/data/index/?skip= 
 {offset}&sort=best_deals&game=csgo&all=0"
)

offset = 0

while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get(URL.format(offset=offset)).json()
        for data in response["items"]:
            namer=(data["name"])

        
   
    
    
        offset += 50

 

        if offset == 8000:
            break
  

        listo.append(namer)
        namelist = sorted(set(listo))

        for names in namelist:
        
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}

            data = {"name":names}

            r = requests.post('https://waxpeer.com/api/get-sales-history', 
headers=headers, json=data)

            history=r.json()

            count=[i['count'] for i in history['data']]

            counter = [list(map(int, x)) for x in count]

            avgn=(numpy.mean(counter))

            itemss=(namer, avgn)



        
            itemois=pd.DataFrame({
                'Names':[namer],
                'Average Selling Price': [avgn]}). dropna()
        
            print(itemois)



    except KeyError:
        break

itemois.to_excel('JohnsWaxpeerDatabase.xlsx')
```

full code as requested, sorry for the messiness.

When I try exporting the database to excel it only adds the first row.
Any Ideas?

Comment: I suspect that when you are writing to excel, you are not writing all the records and this usually happens if you have a loop and you are not really appending all the rows. pls, share the code where you are building the data frame and writing it to excel. for export from database, show us code which is doing this.

Comment: The full code has been updated, do you understand where i am going wrong?

Comment: line is overwriting your past data `itemois=pd.DataFrame({
                'Names':[namer],
                'Average Selling Price': [avgn]}). dropna()` you need to append the data in list or so.

Comment: Added my response in answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comment clarification, here are two tweaks

1. Added a list for appending rows
2. np.means was throwing an exception
   because you had a list like following in counter

`counter=[[3],[1, 1]]`

```
my_dict_list=[] # added to your code, to append the dictionary
#break_counter=0
while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get(URL.format(offset=offset)).json()
        for data in response["items"]:
            namer=(data["name"])
            offset += 50
            if offset == 8000:
                break
            listo.append(namer)
            namelist = sorted(set(listo))
            for names in namelist:
        
                headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}

                data = {"name":names}

                r = requests.post('https://waxpeer.com/api/get-sales-history', headers=headers, json=data)
                history=r.json()
                count=[i['count'] for i in history['data']]

                counter = [list(map(int, x)) for x in count]

                try:
                    print(counter)
                    avgn=(numpy.mean(counter))
                except Exception as e: # new lines added to handle exception
                    print(f"Exception:{e} for request {r}") # new lines added to handle exception
                    counter= [e1 for e in counter for e1 in e] # new lines added to handle exception, i.e flat the list
                    avgn=(numpy.mean(counter)) # new lines added to handle exception
                    

                itemss=(namer, avgn)
                my_dict_list.append({'Names':namer,'Average Selling Price': avgn}) # # added to your code, to append to list

    except KeyError:
        break
```

build the dataframe and dropna

```
df=pd.DataFrame(my_dict_list)
df.dropna()
```

output: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Because `itemois` is override every loop, you can store them in a list. And [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them after loop finished.

```py
dfs = []

while True:
    try:
        ...
        for names in namelist:
            ...
            itemois=pd.DataFrame({
                'Names':[namer],
                'Average Selling Price': [avgn]}). dropna()

            dfs.append(itemois)

itemois = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```